# Show mutltiple tables seperated by page breaks using Active Reports, C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, activereports

I am using Active Reports 7 with C# and SQL Server. I have a query which has a parameter say `AUDID`. I want to show data based on this parameter as below.

1. when `AUDID = AUD1`, then show the data for `AUD1`, which gets the data from the SQL query
2. when `AUDID = AUD1` and `AUD2` which are checkboxes, then the same data should show on different reports  1 for AUD1 and the other for AUD2 (the same query is used to get the data for different AUD's)
3. when `AUDID = ALL`, we need to show a tabled data for each AUD in different pages

Could you please suggest me what can be solution to create such a report?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is the data coming back as a single resultset?  or do you issue two queries to get each AUDID?

if they are both in the same resultset then create a group on AUDID and you can set pageBreakAfter on the groupfooter so the new AUDID would end up on a new page.

if you would like send your requirements to tech support on our site activereports.grapecity.com and one of our engineers can help you further.

Comment: no they are not in the same result set  they are in a different result set , each would have a different layout that needs to be shown in the different pages

Comment: I have already posted it in the active reports site but have not received any responses as yet , please find the link below.: http://arhelp.grapecity.com/groups/topic/show-data-on-the-same-report-for-multiple-query-ouput-seperated-by-page-breaks/

Comment: I see.  I just the post in the forums.   I am having  a hard time picturing what you need.   So the user enters one or more AUDID and for each of those AUDID you need a separate query/resultset and a separate table potentially containing different layout.   How many AUDIDs are there and how many potential layouts.   AR supports conditional layouts and multiple tables and of course parameters, but we need to figure out how to put it all together based on your requirements.  share you email with us and I will assign an engineer to work on this with you.

Comment: @MarioNoronha - I believe Sergey was able to help you solve your issue.  It is a very unique situation and we will into ways to make it easier in the future.  thank you for using ActiveReports